# Erro DLL Conexão FireDac com PostgreSQL

Tags: delphi, postgresql, dll, firedac

Estou com o erro de DLL não encontrada ao fazer uma conexão com o PostgreSQL utilizando o componente FireDAC.

**Erro:**

> [FireDAC][Phys][PG]-314. Cannot load vendor library [C:\EXE\libpq.dll]. Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.

O detalhe é que já copiei a DLL para o diretório da aplicação, também para teste copiei a dll para o System32 e o Syswow64, porém o erro persiste.

Estou com o Microsoft C++ package 2015 instalado, conforme pede na documentação documentação da embarcadero:
[Wiki Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_PostgreSQL_(FireDAC))

Outro teste que realizei foi pelo componente FireDAC tentar realizar a conexão, inclusive no compoente do drive do Postgres apontei a propriedade VendorLib para a DLL, porém, novamente o mesmo erro.

Alguém possui mais alguma sugestão?
Grato desde já.

Comment: Outra informação que possa ajudar: a aplicação foi desenvolvida em plataforma 32bit, sendo assim instalei o postgree x32/x86

Comment: Instala o Postgresql x64 e veja se o problema persiste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o conhecimento de todos, o problema foi resolvido. Para o PostgreSQL funcionar corretamente é necessário copiar as seguintes DLLs para a pasta da aplicação:

- Libeay32.dll
- SSLeay32.dll
- Intl.dll
- Libpq.dll

Copiar essas DLLs do diretório bin da instalação do PostgreSQL.

Comment: x64: `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`, `libintl-8.dll`, `libpq.dll`, `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`, `msvcr120.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Sei q já seu problema foi resolvido, porem gostaria de deixar minha contribuição pra outros..

Recomendo fazer o download dessas dll e colocar na pasta do executável em produção,  na plataforma x86, porque os executáveis por padrão no Delphi é 32bis

no site oficial https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/dll/

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, o problema foi resolvido quando adicionei no Form, o Object Inspector FDPhysPgDriverLink1. Na propriedade VendorHome, vai ter um diretório, apaguei o \lib e pronto.
Funcionou normalmente depois que eu fiz isso.

Answer (score 0):

No caso, se você quer prototipar sua aplicação em tempo de design, precisa colocar as dlls no diretório do delphi (ver respostas acima, todas estão corretas)

No meu caso, eu copiei as dlls tanto para o diretório do meu projeto quanto para o diretório onde o delphi está instalado

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin
D:\Projetos\Projeto1\Debug\Win32
D:\Projetos\Projeto1\Release\Win32\

eu coloquei as dlls dentro de uma pasta

\Drivers\Pg\x86\

entao ficou assim

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\Drivers\Pg\x86
D:\Projetos\Projeto1\Debug\Win32\Drivers\Pg\x86
D:\Projetos\Projeto1\Release\Win32\Drivers\Pg\x86\

Eu arrastei um componente PGDriverLib e na property VendorHome eu coloquei "Drivers\Pg\x86"

Funcionou em todos os cenários
Em modo de design
Em modo de debug
Compilado em modo Release

Para distribuir o software copie a mesma pasta Drivers\Pg\x86 para a mesma pasta da aplicacao

Comment: Isto funciona também para outros bancos. MySql é o mesmo procedimento.